# Template for setting branch policies for repos

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch

We are in the process of migrating all our repositories from Github to VSTS finally and getting our automated build and deployment process setup as well as a new working flow.

While setting up our repositories we had to go through each one individually and configure the branch policies. It got me thinking is there not a way to create some sort of branch policy template that can be reused for your other repos or new repos? I couldn't find anything in the settings that indicated otherwise but I've been having a hard time sifting through all the ways you can customize VSTS that I'm sure I could have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no way bulk set branch policies for branches and repositories.

I posted an user voice [Have branch police template to store the branch policies usually set for most branches](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32334574-have-branch-police-template-to-store-the-branch-po), you can vote and follow up.

And there is also another user voice [Share single branch policy by multiple branches](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/14911392-share-single-branch-policy-by-multiple-branches) which suggest the similar functions to set branch policies for multiple branches, you can also vote and follow up.