# Setting VSTS Policy configuration for a repositor's branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, branch

I have a VSTS repo that I am using with GIT applying the GIT-Flow concepts.    In my master and development branches I have set various policy configurations such as required approval on Pull Requests, etc. This works well for what we want to do.

Anyhow my question is:

When I follow a gitflow approach and create a release branch, I would like the policies on that branch to also have approvals for PUSH commands similar to the master and development branches.  From what I can tell the only way to do that is to manually go in after the branch is made and set those settings.

I wondered if there are ways you can set those by default or have them cascade down or something so that the policies will be certain to be applied and won't need a manual step?

I would think even if something could be scripted out that could satisfy my needs.

I assume that [Template for setting branch policies for repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402461/template-for-setting-branch-policies-for-repos) is the same and this has to be manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to do it automatically for now just as you find. You can vote up the user voice mentioned in the question you referred.

But if you want to do it by script, you can call the VSTS Rest API to configure the policy settings. Refer to this link for details: [Policy - Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/policy/configurations/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1).